# How to get a module hierarchy graph?

Tags: python, code-analysis

I have a fairly big python project which is getting a bit out of control. I would like to get a graphical overview of which modules are importing which other modules.

Are there any tools to help me get this kind of graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to visualize dependencies. I haven't used it, but the first result in Google when searching for `python dependency graph` looks promising: https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps

Comment: And that is exactly what I was looking for.